# Java - Handling a POJO via interfaces or by the POJO class itself? Efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, oop, interface

I've been looking through some projects of games similar to the one I am developing and I've seen two ways of handling methods to mutate the Player.

Notes: a car, house, and job are the only three things to be handled. (only 3 items this game includes; - so a fourth item like family will never exist) However, this does not mean that no more fields will be added and mutated to the player class. (100+ more fields to be added)

Here is the generic java framework and usage (Which I am using at the moment):

```
@Data //lombok for setters/getters
public final class Player {

    private final Car car = new Car();

    private final Job job = new Job("none");

    private final House hosue = new House();

    public void makeHouseWooden() { //the method exists here in player class
        house.setMode(wooden);
        house.incrementTimesEdited(1);
        house.refreshIfInside();
        house.configureNewEnvironment();
    }

}
```

This is what I've been seeing on other projects and would like to follow as the player class gets pretty big with methods:

```
@Data //lombok for setters/getters
public final class Player implements ContentWorker {

    private final Car car = new Car();

    private final Job job = new Job("none");

    private final House hosue = new House();

    @Override
    public Player player() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

and the interface handles methods relating to the fields in Player.java

```
public interface ContentWorker {

    Player player();

    public default void makeHouseWooden() {
        House house = player().getHouse();
        house.setMode(wooden);
        house.incrementTimesEdited(1);
        house.refreshIfInside();
        house.configureNewEnvironment();
    }

}
```

I want to change to the second model because if I continue as I am at the moment then the Player class will become huge. (over 3000 lines)
This way I can keep the Player class for the fields only (better readability) and I could also have an interface which handles all house methods, another which handles all car methods and another which handles all job methods. (to avoid huge unreadable classes, also more dynamic interaction, easier to find the method you want)

```
public final class Player implements HouseWorker, CarWorker, JobWorker {
```

Which is better or more "efficient" and "easy to use" for my predicament?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a method getHouse() in the ContentWorker instead of player()? That way the ContentWorker is not bound to the Player-class.

Comment: @RalfRenz What do you mean? getHouse() is the getter in Player class, and it is being used by contentWorker to mutate vars in the house class. It would be pointless to have 2 getters that do the same thing